# How to use a folder variable when calling a powershsell script

Tags: vba, excel

Firstly, apologies for confusing question. I hope the below gives more explanation as to what I am asking.

Within VBA I need to use a variable to point to an Excel cell which holds the location of the Powershell script, as this may be different for different users.

When I run the below code it doesn't bring any error. The window pops up and disappears. I think it is something to with the syntax here- ""Shell". When i enter the location it works perfectly.

```
Private Sub Export_Click()

Dim Asn  As String
Dim QuestionToMessageBox As String
Dim Power As String

Shell = Worksheets("Input").Range("A4").Value

    QuestionToMessageBox = "Are you sure you would like to proceed?"

    Ans = MsgBox(QuestionToMessageBox, vbYesNo, "Are you sure you would like to proceed?")

    If Asn = vbNo Then
         Exit Sub
    Else

            Call Shell("powershell -noexit -file ""Shell", vbMaximizedFocus)
    End If
MsgBox "The Exportation has completed", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad idea to use the name of a VBA command as a variable name, so my first suggestion is to change your variable `Shell` to something like `ScriptToRun` - so

```
Dim ScriptToRun As String
ScriptToRun = Worksheets("Input").Range("A4").Value
```

And then the correct way to embed that within your invocation of the `Shell` command would be:

```
Shell "powershell -noexit -file """ & ScriptToRun & """", vbMaximizedFocus
```

or maybe just

```
Shell "powershell -noexit -file " & ScriptToRun, vbMaximizedFocus
```

if you don't want the location to be wrapped with `"`s.  (Usually the double-quote marks are needed if the file/path includes any embedded spaces.)

---

You also have a typo in your code (`asn` -v- `ans`).  You can avoid spending hours looking for that sort of thing if you use `Option Explicit` as the first line in your code module.  That will then give a compiler error every time you use a variable that hasn't been correctly declared, so would tell you that the variable `ans` was not declared.

It may be a bit more work declaring all your variables, but it will save you time in the long run.